# div columns (one below another)

Tags: html

I have a question about divs.  I have a table with a `td` in it. 
In that `td`, I want to insert div's. They are smaller than the `td` width and with float left, so they arrange alongside one another.

Here's the tricky part: each one of them have a specific `margin-top` and a specific `height`.  What i need is a div to be placed below (not alongside) another if the sum of the margin and the sum of the upsider is smaller than the margin of the downsider.

I'm attaching a link to an image so you can see it better: (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3109622/divs.png). What i need is the green div to be placed below the orange one.

Edit to add my code.  The column you're seeing:

```
<td>
    <div class="columna" style="background: #FAA957; height: 8em; margin-top: 5em;"></div>
    <div class="columna" style="background: #F4828C; height: 3em; margin-top: 10em;"></div>
    <div class="columna" style="background: #C4E24D; height: 7em; margin-top: 15em;"></div>
</td>
```

And the style:

```
.columnCenter .columna {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Are these divs dynamic in nature or can you explicity style the green div? If you can a clear:left on the green div should work.

Comment: They are print dinamically through js >.<

Comment: hi, user1402745 show your code, it helps to answer.

Answer (score 0):

apply clear left for the green div.

```
<div style="float:left; width:10px; color:#0CC; height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; background:#F60; clear:left"></div>
```

Clear left will move the div down.

A quick example similar to your image:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="200px" height="50px">
<div style="float:left; width:10px; color:#0CC; height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; background:#0CC"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:10px; color:#0CC; height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; background:#F60"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:10px; color:#0CC; height: 20px;  background:#99C; clear:left"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `float:left` style for each `div`, and keep in mind total 3 `div`'s height should not exceed `td` height..